# Problems with GWT app when deploying in Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: gwt, tomcat

I'm using

- GWT Framework
- GXT 4.2
- MySQL
- Gilead
- c3p0
- Hibernate

When I run my application from eclipse works perfectly each remote procedures, then generated the compiler war with google and I'm success all 6 reviews finally copy the generated war (which is a folder and not a. War) in webapps apache-tomcat 7 and deploy my application apparently works but fails in the following:

- Does not perform well validations logic to insert data into the database, sometimes it works and sometimes not.
- When I make a data operation such as recovering "registered assists a teacher" sometimes the data recovering well and sometimes not (it should be noted that the tuples retrieved before passing through a logic that puts them a state "delay" by according to the time recorded example), it seems that failure is part of the java code, but when I run it from eclipse works perfectly the same example.
- Every so long (8 hours average) to open the web page with the server path I get "Connection error with bd" or "error retrieving fields to the combo box" (I do this before showing)

If you could help me I'll be a thousand grateful, I think the google compiler does not compile the code in java good or not can be wrong.

Part of my hibernate.cfg files is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration         
  DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-
  3.0.dtd">
  <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>

    <property  name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://domain/bd</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property 
          name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        <property
```

name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvide
            
        1
            5
            20
            300
            0
            100
            SELECT 1;

Comment: Youshould ask a question in the subject

Comment: Can you paste the tomcat information from the error logs? Tere was a problem with connection pooling (C3P0) and tomcat I also encountered in the past that did not exist on other java app servers.

Comment: Helping you without logs is as pointless as trying to guide home a friend whose location is unknown. Why not posting logs?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the default 8h connection reset of mysql and hibernate.

It is impossible, that the hibernate (pure java, not gwt compiled to JS) can influence the database connection.

But your hibernate configuration seems to be correct.

Comment: accurate, although I find it strange that no function or work well sometimes and sometimes not (testing the same data), it should work fine when run in eclipse and when in the server fails?

Comment: There can be many possibilities, why code runs in dev, but not in prod. MultiThread Issues, too many  connections used, because of not putting them back into the pool, differest hostnames or a firewall.

Comment: this system using a single user and I do not have problems with the connection pool, you think with the c3p0 settings in hibernate.cfg work well??

I tried removing the c3p0 but still the same, if not the problem will be the gilead because usually use DTO, also used a SessionManager personalized with singleton.

The strange thing is that there is another module in the system that works perfectly from the apache.